# OpenGL Glsl shader use in Monogame

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, effect, monogame

Is there a way to use **GLSL** effects in monogame framework (using WindowsGL template project)?

I know that if I used HLSL I could just use their tool to convert the shader, however I really wanted to use glsl.

It's amazing, but I couldn't even find any reference of people searching for this, is it so unthinkable?

Edit:

[This looks interesting](https://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/471179), but not implemented yet

Comment: `[solved]`? post your solution!

Comment: since you have the answer, please post it as a valid answer and auto-accept. That way the current thread will be "closed" (more like inactive), until further informations.

Comment: with the amount of rep(?) that I have, I had to wait so was only able to do it today, thanks.


I'll accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not implemented yet.

Monogame developers are working on it though.

thanks